# Python, Plot three charts in plt.subplots(2,2)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

By using

```
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
```

I create a figure with four sub-plots like this

[image]

what if I just want three plots in the figure?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would remove the last one

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax[1,1].remove()
```